# Using Google Guava CacheLoader for custom class as Key

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to use Google Guava CacheLoader for custom class as Key.

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface RecordAggregatorRequest {
    String name();

    String date();
}


private final LoadingCache<RecordAggregatorRequest, Map<String, Record>> recordsCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
            .build(CacheLoader.from(recordAggregator::getRecords));
```

And then calling like:

```
final Map<String, Record> recordsMap = recordsCache.get(aggregatorRequest);
```

`recordAggregator::getRecords` is being called every time. I suspect it is because hashcode for `RecordAggregatorRequest` key is different every time even though the member values are same. Is there a way to make it work for the custom class as Key?

Comment: Have you tried fixing your hashcode logic so it's not "different every time"?

Comment: Currently, I haven't written any logic for calculating hash. Sort of relying on Google Guava to do that for me (which is not working)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement appropriate hashcode and equals methods on your custom java class.

Guava does not understand the inner details of your class and relies on meaningful implementations of equals and hashcode. These objects should also be effectively immutable once they are added to the cache or else bad things may happen.

Most code generators can generate good equals/hashcodes for you, or you could also use [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case, the key is an Immutable interface. So equals and hashcode override won't work here. Is there a way to make it work on this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have a correct equals and hashCode on an immutable type?  It sounds like the problem is in `@Value.Immutable`.

Comment: Do you mean Google Guava should calculate same hashcode for different objects with same member values?

Comment: If `@Value.Immutable` comes from immutables.io, then it computes hashCode and equals properly (based on object's properties which both are strings in this case).